# Registering Event In Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, conventions

I think there is only `Registered` event in `IComponentRegistry` interface as implemented. What I was wondering for: **Is there any way to intercept every registration while registering time to add additional functionalities to it.** Such as `Registering` event ?

For example, I have an interface `IApplicationService`. This is a marker interface to register all `ApplicationServices` as the conventional way. This interface will allow me to register all **ApplicationServices** in my layer which designed with DDD approach. So, I want to apply *UnitOfWork* **as default** to all **ApplicationServices** on **Registration** time by intercepting them and decorating them an *UnitOfWorkInterceptor*. This approach leads that, I need a `Registering` event to apply any `As<>` or `InterceptedBy<>` methods to registering component as the addendum.

This means that update a component on registration time, i suppose. How can i treat my registrations with that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an *Autofac* module which has a `AttachToComponentRegistration` method which will be triggered for every registration

```
public class XModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    { 
        // do whatever you want with registration
    }
}
```

the `AttachToComponentRegistration` will be triggered for every registration : past and future.

The `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2` extension works with `RegistrationBuilder` whereas `Module` works with `Registration`. AFAIK there is no way to intercept 
`IRegistrationBuilder` and automatically call methods on it, thus there is no easy way to use the `InterceptedBy` and so on method on a `Module`.

You can by the way do it using classic Castle.Core interception without relying on `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2` with something like this :

```
public class XModule : Module
{
    public XModule()
    {
        this._generator = new ProxyGenerator();
    }

    private readonly ProxyGenerator _generator;

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, 
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        if (registration.Services
                        .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
                        .Any(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IApplicationService)))
        {
            registration.Activating += Registration_Activating;
        }
    }

    private void Registration_Activating(Object sender, ActivatingEventArgs<Object> e)
    {
        Object proxy = this._generator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(
            e.Instance.GetType(),
            e.Instance,
            e.Context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IInterceptor>>().ToArray());

        e.ReplaceInstance(proxy);
    }
}
```

You can browse the [source code](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy) of the `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2` module to understand how you can integrate *Castle.Core* with *Autofac*.

Comment: How can i apply `InterceptedBy<>` with this approact to existing component without overriding it?

Comment: @OguzhanSoykan I edited my post to include more sample

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was predicting that this answer will be come :) I already implemented this approach and also you told what i was wondering that *there is no way to intercept  IRegistrationBuilder*. So, I'm gonna mark your solution as answer but, I think we need to intercept *IRegistrationBuilder* eventually...